# Difference in sha1's

Tags: openssl, sha1

Trying to figure out why my base64 sha1's are different.

I get

> Password 'a' Result 'hvfkN/qlp/zhXR3cuerq6jd2Z7g='

When using my java function. I can verify that using some random online tools.

However when I try to verify using the command line and openssl

```
echo a | openssl dgst -binary -sha1 | openssl base64
```

I get

> P3hoUOOHVQ/auDbtfm3Igd4jABs=

That maybe it was  utf8/bash thing, so I tried

```
echo 'a' | iconv --from-code=ISO-8859-1 --to-code=UTF-8 | openssl dgst -binary -sha1 | openssl base64
```

Same result.

What am I missing?

Edit:

Sites that verify my original result
http://www.tools4noobs.com/online_php_functions/sha1/ to calculate hex sha1

86f7e437faa5a7fce15d1ddcb9eaeaea377667b8

Convert hex to base64
http://tomeko.net/online_tools/hex_to_base64.php?lang=en

hvfkN/qlp/zhXR3cuerq6jd2Z7g=

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`echo` appends a newline, which will be included in the digest computation; try `printf` instead.  Also be wary of other parts of the pipeline adding extraneous newlines or other characters.

Comment: Now that I know that, man echo shows that an 'echo -n' accomplishes the same thing.